# Is this equation of vector form of gravity correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

There is this equation in my physics book about *gravity as a form of vector*. It initially confused me, but after doing a bit of research, I suppose $\hat{r}$ should be replaced by $\vec{r}$

[image]

Am I correct? Or is it something else?

Comment: It is a typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo.  Should be
$$\vec{\mathbf F}_g =-G \dfrac{m_1m_2}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat r} $$ or by substituting $\mathbf{\hat r}  = \mathbf{\vec r}/r$ you get
$$
\vec{\mathbf F}_g =-G \dfrac{m_1m_2}{r^3} \mathbf{\vec r}
$$